# More Than Two main Method in Visual Studio application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

In my project I am having more than two Main method with same signature. One is a winForm and other one is Console class.

How to set any one of them as entry point.

I declared `[STAThread]` before one main method to set entry point but It's not working?

I am using Visual Studio express 2010

Comment: [STAThread] attribute is not used for entry point.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go into the project properties by right clicking the project in the solution explorer and click properties. On the first tab you will see a drop down list for the entry point. Select the appropriate main method.

Comment: I am not getting any dropdown list. (Not Set) is alone there. If all are of same type(either windows or Console) then we get that. But my project have both, forms and console

Comment: It's labeled "Startup Object". Here's a screen shot from a fresh console application. http://www.screencast.com/t/27JwRJ0F

Comment: Ya thanks I get that Now, After rebuild the solution I got the Dropdown List. But "Output type" I have to set. It'd be console type or windows application.

Answer (score 8):

`STAThread` doesn't set the entry point - it forces the runtime to use a Single-Threaded Apartment for the thread which executes Main.

As Josh says, you need to set the Startup Object in project properties. If that isn't showing in VS Express, you may need to force it to show advanced build properties: Open Tools\Options and check "Show advanced build configuration" in Projects and Solutions.

Note that your application *either* has to be a console app *or* a WinForms app. It can only be built as one (per configuration, anyway). You'll either end up with a console showing when you start is as a WinForms app, or no console showing when you start it as a console app.

Have you considered putting the bulk of the logic in a class library, and then creating two wrapper applications - one WinForms and one console - which just display the relevant UI and then delegate to the class library?

Comment: U r right. I got the solution, one time either forms or console only built. No I haven't tried ur Idea. Can u be in bit more details. Thanx

Comment: @Pawan: What more details do you need? Use three projects: one class library, one WinForms, one console. Add references from each of the console app and the WinForms app to the class library, which is where you put the bulk of your logic.

Comment: Actually you can build it as a Windows EXE then show a console conditionally (based on a command line parameter or something) using AllocConsole but it's a bit involved and it has some undesirable side effects. If you're interested, see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348195/allocate-a-console-for-a-winform-application

Comment: @Josh: Yes, I was trying to keep things relatively simple :)

Answer (score 4):

If program have two main method compiler get confution so run c# program put main class give

```
public Class one

{
public static void main()
{
System.console.writeline("One");
}

public Class two
{
public static void main()
{
System.console.writeline("Two");
}
}
```

run C# in console

**CSC Multimain.cs /main:one**

- Output
  One

**CSC Multimain.cs /main:two**

- Output
  Two

Comment: nice suggestion to manually run a c# file using VS cmd prompt. I think the OP wants to use in VS itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a Main method in every class you declare. Some programmers take advantage of this to build a small test app into each class they declare.

However, if you declare more than one **Main method** among the classes of your project, you’ll need to indicate to the IDE which one you would like to be the app’s **entry point**. To do so:

1. With the project open in Visual Studio, select **Project >
   [ProjectName] Properties**... (where **[ProjectName]** is the name of your
   project).
2. Select the class containing the Main method that should be the entry
   point from the **Startup object** list box.

Answer (score 0):

You can put more then one main method in single program but program with one main method will be compiled at a time for example :
Copy paste this code in editor and change name Release in first line and see the change

```
#define Release 
using System;
class Program
{  
#if Release==true
    public static void Main(string[] args) //for enemy
    {     
        Console.WriteLine("go to  hell");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


#elif Release==false
    static void Main(string[] args) //for friend
    {    

         Console.WriteLine("hello ");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

#endif 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do by this way but i dont know how to set which main method will be entry point

```
 public static void Main(string args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is second main method");
    }

   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.Main("second main method");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be solved easily by steps here
1. Open the solution
2 split the two classes into separate class files
3. click on the "Project" tab from main menu bar
4. Move to cursor to the Property
5. Select the desired class name you wanted to run  for "Reference Path"
6. Compile the project, the error will be ride off.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think this will work. It won't even compile and complaint that the project has two main methods. There must only be one `public static main` method in the project. You have to rename/remove the second one.

By the way exactly why would you like to keep both of them?

Comment: That's right, for two main methods it VS feels ambiguity, which is entry point. And that was my ques How to set particular entry point? 

A project that opt user to go retrieve data in console or in windows

Comment: Not true. You can have two main methods in a single project.

Comment: ya I mean we can have... but which one is entry point is imp.

Comment: -1, because it's perfectly possible. I do it all the time for talks - I have one entry point which finds others.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I am OK with having multiple ones. But, how do you go about finding others? Just intrigued...

Comment: @Kanini: I look for static Main methods which either have no parameters or a String[] parameter. The code is in MiscUtil as ApplicationChooser - see http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil