# Hello World! -- C#

Tags: c#

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have tried `Console.Read();, Console.ReadLine();`, and also none.  I have also tried `Ctrl F5`.  I have found no other suggestions while searching.  I am using Visual Studio Express if it's relevant.  Obviously, I am trying to have the program say, "Hello world!"  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Miscellaneous
{
    class Hello_World_
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Error   1   `Program 'c:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Visual Studio Workspace\Miscellaneous\Miscellaneous\obj\Debug\Miscellaneous.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Miscellaneous.Hello_World_.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.   C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Visual Studio Workspace\Miscellaneous\Miscellaneous\Hello World!.cs 11  21  Miscellaneous`

Error   2   `Program 'c:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Visual Studio Workspace\Miscellaneous\Miscellaneous\obj\Debug\Miscellaneous.exe' has more than one entry point defined: 'Miscellaneous.Program.Main()'.  Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.    C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\Visual Studio Workspace\Miscellaneous\Miscellaneous\Program.cs  15  21  Miscellaneous`

Comment: did you visualize the output? --> In VS menu View --> output

Comment: @Sam Knox I am trying to have the program say, "Hello world!" what you mean by the word "say" ? Is opens cmd window?

Comment: `Main()` - capitalization matters

Comment: I just visualized the output...now the option to run the program is no longer there.

Comment: try running the the output exe from the command line.. Also more tutorials here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1sx6ed2(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I tried to change it to Main, but it says my program is running now. But I do not have it running as far as I know!

Comment: Right click in the menu area and enable the "Standard" menu --> there you can see the start and stop icons to debug and stop the app

Answer (score 3):

The method must be called `Main` with capital M, to be an "entry point" of the program.

Additionally (thanks to the comments), the last of your `using` directives is pointing to a non-existent namespace. What namespaces exist in the `mscorlib` assembly depends on the .NET version you're using.. The only `using` you need for this, is `using System;`.

Also, based on the update of your question, you have in the same solution two classes containing a `Main()` method, namely `class Hello_World_` and `class Program`. For that to compile, you must set which `Main()` is the start-up method (entry point). In Visual Studio, on the right, right-click on the project (or class) inside your solution which you want to set as start-up project.

Comment: I renamed it to Main. It now says there are build errors.

Comment: @SamKnox Weird. I renamed it to `Main` but it runs. There are thousands of build errors. You might want to specify which one you got

Comment: Could be related to [this](http://ideone.com/JGYFGS)

Comment: @SamKnox Read the build error messages.

Comment: It suggests that I compile it with main. I do not see the option.

Comment: I just deleted the project. I will redo it. Thanks for help!

Comment: Still having the issue after deleting everything and making it brand new!

Comment: I have added the error codes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @SamKnox See my edit. Having more than one `Main` method is related to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4406153/1336654), and to the "Remarks" paragraph of [this doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't use the **Console Application** template for your project. ([Here's how that works when creating a new project](https://www.windowsazure.com/media/devcenter/dotnet/creating-a-console-application.png))

If you didn't create the project using the above method, make sure the program's output type is set to **Console Application** and the startup object is set to `Miscellaneous.Hello_World_`

You can set both **output type** and **startup object** in the project properties: [**Here's how**](http://rbwhitaker.wdfiles.com/local--files/console-windows/console-application.png)

Comment: Yes, I agree. In a console application the Main method has also arguments like Main(object[] args)