# Can we have 2 Main methods in a single class?

Tags: c#, .net

I know we can have a main method on different classes. But can we have a class which contains 2 main methods and they both have different arguments. Can I able to run this program?

```
Class Program
{
 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   System.Console.WriteLine("Main Method 1")
  }

 public static void Main()
  {
   System.Console.WriteLine("Main Method 2")
  }
}
```

If yes, how to run it?
I'm just doing this for learning purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just try it out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406026/more-than-two-main-method-in-visual-studio-application

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why have two `Main` methods? What is the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: No, not possible if they are in the same class

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the StartupObject compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point.
follow here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line

Comment: For reference: Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line

Comment: Which means: no, it's not possible since OP wants to have two `Main` methods in the same class. It's only possible with the StartupObject compiler option if they are in different classes.

Comment: its work to different class